# Fedra-21 will be delayed?

Tags: fedora

Every half a year, a new version of fedora is released. 
However fedora-21 is later for one year compared with fedora-20.

Is there any problem for the developers of fedora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no problems. This is due to Fedora.next (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora.next) initiative. Fedora 21 will come with some new things, more specifically a number of products: Fedora Workstation, Fedora Server, ...